# UE4 Image Asset From String

Tags: unreal-4, image, asset-management

I have a custom widget with an image component.  I want to change the image dynamically based on a string from a data table.
How do I do this?

Comment: Where is the iamge located? Is it on the web, the computer's filesystem, a uasset inside your project or something else?

Comment: It is an image asset that is already registered in Unreal (already is a uasset).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**C++**
You can use the `LoadObject` function to find and load and object at runtime. Full documentation is available from Epic Games [here](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/API/Runtime/CoreUObject/UObject/LoadObject/).
For loading an image the following should work:

```
GridTexture = LoadObject<UTexture2D>(NULL, TEXT("/Engine/EngineMaterials/DefaultWhiteGrid.DefaultWhiteGrid"), NULL, LOAD_None, NULL);
```

**Blueprint**
As of yet there is no native implementation, but it is included in [Rama's Victory Plugin](https://forums.unrealengine.com/development-discussion/blueprint-visual-scripting/4014-39-rama-s-extra-blueprint-nodes-for-you-as-a-plugin-no-c-required?p=1039867#post1039867).

[image: The Load object from asset path node]

Select the class you want to want to load and give it the reference path of your asset. The loaded asset will be an `Object` so you will have to cast it to  `Texture2D`. Then you can store it as a variable or directly set the image of your widget.
Below is an example of using this with a DataTable with some assets.

[image: full example with datatable]

To get a usable reference, simply right click an asset and select *Copy Reference*.

Comment: I tested this, and it definitely worked.  Thanks again.  Note: To get the "reference path", right-click on the asset in the asset viewer and select "Copy reference".